# Strange behavior of a hyperoperator

Tags: raku

I found out this strange behavior of a hyperoperator:

```
say 0 != 0;                 # False

my @a = 0, 0, 0;
say @a «==» @a;             # [True True True]
say @a «!=» @a;             # [True True True] <--- why?
say @a «!==» @a;            # [False False False]
```

The `!=` infix operator is defined [here](https://docs.raku.org/routine/!=,%20infix%20%E2%89%A0) as *equivalent to !==* while apparently it's not, at least when used in a hyperoperator.

The problem seems to be related to the specific value (zero), since using a different value returns the expected result.
Besides, using `0 but True` works fine:

```
@a = 0 but True, 0 but True, 0 but True;
say @a «!=» @a;             # [False False False]
```

I'm using Rakudo 2022.03.

Is this a bug or something I cannot grasp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It most definitely is a bug, as this:

```
my @a = 0, 0, 0;
say HYPER(&infix:<<!=>>, @a, @a);  # [False False False]
```

gives the correct result.  However, what gets passed to `HYPER` is *not* the `&infix:<<!=>>`, but a code block that apparently wraps it (incorrectly).

Investigating further, but please, yes, this is a bug and as such should be reported :-)

EDIT: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4838

EDIT: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/4839 fixes it, but am unsure about the way it fixes it  :-)

EDIT: Fix has been approved by jnthn, merged.  Will be in 2022.04.  Thanks for noting!